# Is set.copy() atomic in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, concurrency, atomic

Suppose we have an instance variable in a class.

```
class MyClass(object):  
    def __init__():  
        self.set1 = set()
```

Is the following operation atomic?

```
set_shallow_copy = self.set1.copy()
```

I've tried to search around, but the only information I've found is that reading instance variables are atomic.

(Edit)
I tried to decompile the bytecode (Python 2.7 on Windows), but it's not too useful. It just shows Python bytecode that calls the `copy` function on `set`.

```
 9 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)  
 12 LOAD_ATTR                1 (copy)  
 15 CALL_FUNCTION            0 
 18 STORE_FAST               1 (s2) 
 21 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
 24 RETURN_VALUE
```

(Edit 2): I wonder if using set2 = set(set1) might be better.

```
         9 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (set)  
         12 LOAD_FAST                0 (set1)  
         15 CALL_FUNCTION            1  
         18 STORE_FAST               1 (set2)  
         21 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)  
         24 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: I was wondering are we working with python3 or python2.7 here?

Comment: Right now I'm using Python 2.7. Will it be different in Python 3?

Comment: Why do you care? Invoking the `copy` method is going to be marginally faster than invoking the built-in `set` constructor, but that has nothing to do with atomicity. What's the goal?

Comment: I suspect it may depend on what you mean by "atomic". Most operations on builtin objects are "atomic" in the sense that they won't let another operation run in another thread break their internal state. That doesn't mean the operations are guaranteed to run in a specific order, just that the object will be in a sane state at the end.

Comment: I see, I think having the object be a sane state at the end would be sufficient. I don't need to guarantee the operations are run in a specific order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CPython since version 3.5, the copy is atomic as far as is visible from Python (because, as usual, of the **global interpreter lock**).  No other thread can alter `set1` while it is being copied, so you will obtain a copy of *some* state that the set was in during the manipulations made by (other) threads.

In **older** versions (like the one tagged here!), the routine that added the elements of the original set to the new (initially empty) copy did not take advantage of the fact that, coming from a `set`, all the values were unique; as such, it uses `==` to rediscover that fact.  If that comparison is implemented in **Python** (or by certain C extensions that release the GIL), then the process can be interrupted by other threads (and fail arbitrarily).

Comment: Are you sure about that, or is there an authoritative reference for that? I just had a script die in a line `my_set_copy = my_set.copy()` with `RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration` (the set was indeed modified from a different thread).

Comment: @bluenote10: With what Python version?  The current implementation doesn’t even need to call a user-defined `__eq__` because it knows the source’s keys are unique.

Comment: That was on a legacy system running Python 2.7.12.

Comment: @bluenote10: Well, that’s the version for which the question was asked, so that’s only fair.  I’ve added information for that version, where the answer is **sometimes**.  Sorry to have stated it too simply before.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks for digging out the differences.